# Cannot create a Queue Manager for IBM MQ 7

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using the WebSphere 7.1. I am following the below steps :
**Creating the queue manager using WebSphere MQ Explorer
Procedure:**

- Start WebSphere MQ Explorer.
- In the Navigator view, right-click the    Queue Managers folder, then
  click New > Queue Manager.The Create Queue Manager wizard opens.
- In the Queue Manager name field, type QM_APPLE.
- Click Next twice.
- Ensure that Automatic is selected from the Select type of queue
  manager startup option.
- Click Next.
- Ensure that the Create listener configured for TCP/IP check box is
  selected.
- If the Finish button is not available, type another port number in
  the Listen on port number field. If the current value is 1414, try
  using a different port number, for example: 1415 or 1416. If the
  default port number of 1414 is not used at this stage, make a note of
  the port number used because you will need it in later stages of this
  tutorial when QM_APPLE serves as a receiving queue manager.
- Click    Finish.

**The Problem is, I am stuck in the Step 2. When i right Click I cannot find "NEW" option to create the Queue. Can anyone tell me Why I am not getting it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a Websphere MQ Server properly installed locally?
I saw such behavior when only Websphere MQ Explorer is installed.
In this case the only point on step 2 is to add a remote Queue Manager.

Comment: how do i check whether its installed properly or not

Comment: open a command prompt and run 'dspmqver -a' command. The command will display details of MQ installed. If you get an error saying 'dspmqver - unknown command' or something like that, then you will need to go to the directory where MQ is typically installed on Windows (I am assuming you are on Windows) i.e Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin. Run the dspmqver command and see what you get.

Comment: @Shashi Its 7.1.0.2 I guess they havent installed the Server version. May be that is the reason not able to show that option. Bcoz i can add a Remote Queue but cannot create a Local Queue.

Comment: Now i am able to get the option "New".. but i get this error msg AMQ7257: The MQ service for installation 'Installation1' (C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ) must be running.
exitvalue = 74

Comment: Do you have admin rights? And also check that MQ user created.

Answer (score 0):

START The MQ Explorer in Administrator mode.

Got the Bin folder of MQ Installation and right click on the mqexpolrer image and select as "Run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Right click > `My computer`
Select and open > `manage`
Expand > `local users and groups`
Select `USerS` 
Right side you user `MUSR_MQADMIN and Properties`.
Uncheck the TickBox > Account is Disabled.
Click `apply and ok`.
Now restart your MQ .

Answer (score 0):

Try to open MQ explorer with the user which we installed MQ. For example it should be mqm and group mqm. Else add your user into mqm group. Then reopen MQ and check.

Answer (score -1):

You should have local admin rights to find New option at Queue managers.
To do this get local admin rights and follow the steps below:

1. Right click my computer
2. Select and open manage
3. Expand local users and groups
4. Select groups at left side
5. Right side you can see all the groups.
6. Double click on mqm group and add your user id.
7. Click apply and ok.
8. Now restart your MQ. You can see the new option after restarting the
   MQ.